# Using files in google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-cloud-storage

I want to transfer the ETL scripts (I used to run them on a local machine) to the google cloud, using the Google Functions + Google Scheduler.
Scripts move data from/to Google Analytics (this is an example).
I have a problem with the location of the key file (.p12). 
I would like to put it in Google Storage and point the way to it.
Currently KEY_FILE_LOCATION = r'c:/local_path/file.p12'.
Connect to google analytics:

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)
    return analytics
```

---

I would like to use

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client ()
bucket = client.get_bucket ('utk_owox')
.....
```

But I can not understand how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that Cloud Functions API client libraries that use application default credentials automatically obtain the built-in service account credentials from the Cloud Functions host at runtime. By default, the client authenticates using the YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com service account.

So if you can configure this service account to have appropriate permissions for the resources that you need to access, it is recommended to relay on it.

Example how to [upload file to the bucket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/530c8bf394912c050d7507fec36307ea1391b777/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py#L151) in python.
Example how to [download file from the bucket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/530c8bf394912c050d7507fec36307ea1391b777/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py#L181) in python:

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))
```

Create credentials [from the file as described here](https://code.markedmondson.me/automatic-google-analytics-data-imports-cloud-storage/):

```
def get_ga_service(bucket):

    download_gcs_file('auth.json', '/tmp/auth.json', bucket)
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            '/tmp/auth.json',
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'])

    # Build the service object.
    return build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
```

Comment: I found the answer in this 
[article](https://code.markedmondson.me/automatic-google-analytics-data-imports-cloud-storage/)

Comment: Great job @АлексейМигачев resolving your own issue. In my example there are that same methods used for download an upload. I did update the answer for better visibility for another users.